# EMR - Mapreduce memory errors

Tags: hadoop, memory, emr, reducers

I'm getting this memory error on my reducers:

`Container is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 6.1 GB of 6 GB physical memory used; 10.8 GB of 30 GB virtual memory used.`

So yeah, there's a physical memory issue what can be resolved by increasing `mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb` BUT I don't understand why it happens.

The more data is getting into the pipe, the more likely it is for this memory issue to occur. The thing is that most of my reducers (about 90%) pass and memory was supposed to be freed as reducers pass because data should have been written to the disk already.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

In YARN by default, containers are pre allocated with memory. In this case all reducer containers will have 6 GB memory regardless of free memory across cluster. The JVM of these containers will not be re-used or shared across containers(not at least in Hadoop2) , that means If the memory on one reducer goes beyond its memory 6 GB limit, it will not grab resources from other free containers (if that's your concern)

Now , why only few reducers are always going above its memory(given 90% passed) hints a possible SKEW in data , which means this reducer might be processing more input groups or more keys than others.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I found the error ... the output of the reducers created too many files and probably having handlers for all those files made the memory to overload. I don't fully understand why I can't have multiple files in response of reducers but maybe it has something to do with the shuffle step.